# PHP cURL isn't storing the session cookie... How to fix this?

Tags: php, cookies, post, curl, session

I am making a class to comunicate with our company API...
I'm using curl to post data and retrieve the response in json.
In the last part of the code (after the class), i log the user into the server (it gives true), but when i try to connect again with curl, he says that i'm not logged!
I've done a google search already and added the **curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,$this->Session_Cookie);** line.

Can anybody give me a light on this?

Thanks in advance ;)

```
if(!class_exists("Microdual")) {
 class Microdual{

  // No caso de a sessão não estar iniciada, iniciar aqui a sessão


  ################
  ################
  ################
  ################ Iniciar funcoes privadas ################

  private function Extra_LoadSession($varname,$otherwise){
   return (!empty($_SESSION[$this->Session_Prefix . $varname])) ? $_SESSION[$this->Session_Prefix . $varname] : $otherwise;
  }
  private function Extra_SaveSession($varname,$value){
   $_SESSION[$this->Session_Prefix . $varname] = $value;
   return true;
  }

  /**
  * $this->API_Comunicate() "Comunicar comandos com os servidores Microdual (enviar e receber)"
  *
  * @param data array "Colocar as variaveis que deseja passar à plataforma (Ver Lista completa de variaveis no Inicio)"
  *
  * @return array or void (false)
  */
  private function API_Comunicate($_data){

   // Converter o array em string (serialize)
   $data = array();    
   while(list($n,$v) = each($_data)){
    $data[] = "$n=$v";
   }
   $data = implode('&', $data);
   // format --> test1=a&test2=b etc.

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->Geral_URLAPI);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_data));
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,$this->Session_Cookie);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   $content = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   if(($content !== false) && (!empty($content))){
    return json_decode($content, true);
   }else{
    return false;
   }
  }


  ################
  ################
  ################
  ################ Iniciar funcoes Públicas ################

  public function Debug_VarDump($varname){
   $string = "<pre>";
   $string .= var_dump($varname);
   $string .= "</pre>";
   return $string;
   exit;
  }
  /**
  * $this->IsLogged() "Verificar se está autenticado no servidor (primeiro localmente, e depois liga ao servidor)"
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function IsLogged(){
   if($logged) return true;
   $logged = $this->Extra_LoadSession("Login_Logged",false);
   if($logged){
    return true;
   }else{
    // Conectar ao servidor
    $dados = $this->API_Comunicate(array());
    if($dados!==false){
     if(!empty($dados['auth']['logged'])){
      return $dados['auth']['logged'];
     }else{
      return false;
     }
    }else{
     return false;
    }
   }
  }

  /**
  * $this->Login() "Executar o Login nos servidores Microdual"
  *
  * @param username string "Colocar aqui o nome de utilizador da sua conta em www.microdual.com"
  * @param password string "Colocar aqui a password da sua conta em www.microdual.com"
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function Login($username,$password){
   if(empty($username) || empty($password)) return false;
   if($this->IsLogged()) return true;

   $receive = $this->API_Comunicate(array(
    "type" => "auth",
    "action" => "add",
    "auth_username" => $username,
    "auth_password" => $password
   ));

   if($receive["auth"]["status"] && $receive["auth"]["logged"]){
    $this->Extra_SaveSession("Login_Logged",true);
    $this->Login_Logged = true;
    return true;
   }else{
    return false;
   }
  }
  /**
  * $this->SMS_Send() "Executar o Login nos servidores Microdual"
  *
  * @param number string "Colocar aqui o numero do telemovel para enviar sms"
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function SMS_Send($number,$msg){
   // Guardar apenas os numeros
   $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $number);
   $msg = trim($msg);

   $receive = $this->API_Comunicate(array(
    "type" => "sms",
    "action" => "add",
    "sms_to" => $number,
    "sms_msg" => $msg
   ));
   return $receive;
  }

  ################
  ################
  ################
  ################ Iniciar variaveis da class ################

  private $Session_Prefix;
  private $Session_Cookie;
  private $Geral_URLAPI;
  private $Login_Logged;




  ################
  ################
  ################
  ################ Iniciar dados da class ################

  function __construct(){
   $this->Session_Prefix = "MYCMSAPI_";
   $this->Session_Cookie = "PHPSESSID=".$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']."; path=/";
   $this->Geral_URLAPI = "http://www.MYCOMPANY.com/MyapiURL";
   $this->Login_Logged = $this->Extra_LoadSession("Login_Logged",false);
  }
 }
}

$Microdual = new Microdual();
if($Microdual->Login("usernamehere","password")){
 $Microdual->Debug_VarDump($Microdual->SMS_Send("93211254","Teste Test Hi :)"));
}else{
 echo "Login com erro";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option is for sending a particular cookie using CURL. The options you are looking for are `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, which specify a file to save and load cookie from.

So you'll have to do something like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
```

Comment: it didn't work! is that file placed on the same folder of the script?

Comment: How doesn't it work? The option value is simply the path to where you want to store your cookies. Whenever you want to use those cookies you'll just have to use a file like that. PHP will create it if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: I had already tryed the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE befor asking here. But now it works, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION was true, and it was iniciating a new cookie session in each conection. Thank you ;)